# "Custom" Widget not showing in WebAppBuilder Developer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I customized the in house WAB Filter widget to do a few additional things. I did not want to lose the standard filter so I just changed the folder name and kept the In House filter widget as is. For some reason, the new Filter widget I customized is not showing up. I changed the "name" as seen below. Also changed the name in Manifiest.json. Is there something else I would need to change to make it a "custom" widget to show up?

[image]

Comment: Beside the name you have to change the baseClass inside your Widget.js. https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/sample-code/create-custom-in-panel-widget.htm